# Rearrange the Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

- The below is my dataframe:
- GS: General Shift
- MS: Morning Shift
- ES: Evening Shift
- 11,22,33 are employee_id

DataFrame:

```
         Day        Date  GS  MS  ES
0     Monday  20/02/2017  11  22  33
1    Tuesday  21/02/2017  22  11  33
2  Wednesday  22/02/2017  33  22  11
```

I would like to convert that DataFrame into below pattern

```
         20/02/2017  21/02/2017  22/02/2017
          Monday       Tuesday    Wednesday
0     11    GS           MS         ES
1     22    ES           GS         MS
2     33    MS           ES         GS
```

So, I am trying to convert the table based on employee_id, I tried `DataFrame.transpose()` but I couldn't get it to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Day', 'Date']).set_index(['Date','Day', 'value']).unstack([0,1])
print (df)
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
value                                 
11            GS         MS         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES         ES         GS
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Day','Date'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=2, name='a')
       .set_index('a', append=True)
       .unstack([1,0])
print (df)
Date 20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
Day      Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
a                                    
11           GS         MS         ES
22           MS         GS         MS
33           ES         ES         GS
```

But if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

```
print (df)
         Day        Date  GS  MS  ES
0     Monday  20/02/2017  11  22  33
1    Tuesday  21/02/2017  22  11  11 < 33 changed to 11
2  Wednesday  22/02/2017  33  22  11
```

Solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and `groupby`, aggregate `join`

```
df =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Day', 'Date'])
        .groupby(['Date','Day', 'value'])['variable']
        .apply(','.join)
        .unstack([0,1])
print (df)
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
value                                 
11            GS      MS,ES         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES       None         GS
```

Solutions with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
#aggregate by first value can be dangerous - lost data
df1 =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Day', 'Date']).pivot_table(index='value',
                           columns=['Day', 'Date'], values='variable', aggfunc='first')
print (df1)
Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
value                                 
11            GS         MS         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES       None         GS

#better aggreagate by sum or join, data are not lost
df1 =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Day', 'Date']).pivot_table(index='value',
                           columns=['Day', 'Date'], values='variable', aggfunc=','.join)
print (df1)
Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
value                                 
11            GS      MS,ES         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES       None         GS

df1 =  pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Day', 'Date']).pivot_table(index='value',
                           columns=['Day', 'Date'], values='variable', aggfunc='sum')
print (df1)
Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
value                                 
11            GS       MSES         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES       None         GS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you melt and then pivot you can get:

**Code:**

```
def by_employee(frame):
    melted = pd.melt(
        frame, value_vars=['GS', 'MS', 'ES'], id_vars=['Day', 'Date'])
    pivot = pd.pivot_table(melted, values='variable', index='value',
                           columns=['Day', 'Date'],
                           aggfunc=lambda x: x.values[0])
    return pivot
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
            Day        Date  GS  MS  ES
         Monday  20/02/2017  11  22  33
        Tuesday  21/02/2017  22  11  33
      Wednesday  22/02/2017  33  22  11
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df)

print(by_employee(df))
```

**Results:**

```
         Day        Date  GS  MS  ES
0     Monday  20/02/2017  11  22  33
1    Tuesday  21/02/2017  22  11  33
2  Wednesday  22/02/2017  33  22  11

Day       Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday
Date  20/02/2017 21/02/2017 22/02/2017
value                                 
11            GS         MS         ES
22            MS         GS         MS
33            ES         ES         GS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the dataframe and create a new dataframe based on the current, only we concat two columns together:

```
data = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    data.append([
        # row[2]: Day, row[1]: Date
        '{} {}'.format(row[2],row[1]), 
        *row[3:],
    ])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: '{} {}'.format(row[2],row[1]),*row[3:],-> invalid syntax

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Earlier version of python do not allow unpacking the list, so you need to unpack them by yourself : data = []
for row in df.itertuples():
 data.append([
  '{} {}'.format(row[2],row[1]), # row[2]: Day, row[1]: Date
  row[3],
  row[4],
  row[5]
 ])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: OK, thanks I will work and updatet the status. I am using python 2.7